# How do I encode an image to be sent as a message?

Tags: ios, ios4, encoding

I can't figure out how to encode and decode a UIImage to send as a message. I have successfully encoded C datatypes, strings, and objects with basic types by implementing the NSCoding protocol for an Object. I have even sent them over a bluetooth connection and decoded and used them successfully.

I can't find any documentation nor Internet examples showing how to send an Image over the wire.

To use my connection, I need to convert the Image to NSData; however, I can't find an API to do that for me. UIImage does not implement encodeWithCoder.

Does anyone have an example that can guide me?

Comment: UIImage does not implement encodeWithCoder:

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to just convert an image to bytes, just as the SQL data type stores an image using the image SQL data type.  I know very little about the iphone-sdk-4.0, but this should get you on the right track.

Comment: I added some code above where I try this approach. But I still haven't gotten it to work.